# Set error in wordpress registration if usermeta with same value is exist for other user

Tags: wordpress

I want to set mobile number in my registration system with usermeta and do not want to allow the same mobile number in registration for other users in wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Here is solution for your question.

You just need to use find query first and search in your post meta that mobile number is available or not.

```
// args to query for your key

 $check_unique_data = array(
     'post_type' => 'your_post_type',
     'meta_query' => array(
       array(
         'key' => 'mobile_post_meta',
         'value' => $mobile_post_meta_value_of_form,
         )
       ),
     'fields' => 'ids'
     );
```

// perform the query

```
 $vid_query = new WP_Query( $check_unique_data );

    $my_ids = $vid_query->posts;
```

// do something if the meta-key-value-pair exists in another post

```
   if ( ! empty( $my_ids ) ) {
// if same found then do not register user or give them error message
 }
```